# Launching blender on the command line results in a error

Tags: error, command-line, osx

When I launch blender from the command line, it results in the following error:

```
❯ Blender -d
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
Blender 2.90.0
Build: 2020-08-31 12:16:14 Darwin Release
argv[0] = Blender
argv[1] = -d
BLT_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
Read prefs: /Users/jayjayjay/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
read file
  Version 280 sub 39 date unknown hash unknown
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'droidsans.ttf', will not be able to display text
uiStyleInit: error, no fonts available
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
Warning! bundled python not found and is expected on this platform. (if you built with CMake: 'install' target may have not been built)
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000000129716dc0 (most recent call first):
[1]    8791 abort      Blender -d
```

Is there a way to resolved this error? All the libraries are in the place they were when they were installed.